# Controls samples in XAML Controls Gallery become corners rounded. Why and how?

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

I find controls in "XAML Controls Gallery" have gotten rounded corners. I don't know when the change happened. Why? Is it a new design for all UWP apps to apply? And how to achieve the same looks in my app?

Answer (score 1):

WinUI is a new UWP. It is now open [sourced](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml)!!! Their [roadmap](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/docs/roadmap.md). The good thing is that they work together with [Uno Platform](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/docs/roadmap.md). Uno is crossplatform and it will be possible to run UWP on Web, iOS, Android.

WinUI will run on all Windows 10 devices which have versions >= 15063
WinUI is intended to fix major developer's problem. They can't use new features and need to ask their customers to update Windows.

This is a [WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/release-notes/winui-2.2) feature:

> CornerRadius attribute was added. Default controls were updated to use
>   slightly rounded corners. Developers can easily customize the corner
>   radius to give your app a unique look if desired.

...

> BorderThickness property was made easier to customize. Default
>   controls were updated to reduce the outlines to be thinner for a
>   cleaner and familiar look.

WinUI 2.0 is stable, but I suspect we should wait for WinUI 3.0 in order to use in our projects.